# How would I print 1, 3, 7, 15, 31 using a loop statement?

Tags: python, loops

```
a = 1
while a <= 31:
    print(a)
    a += 2
```

Is what I have tried. I'm assuming I need to use powers and stuff.

Comment: yes, using exponentiation would make sense

Comment: First of all, do you know what the pattern is? What's the next number after 31?

Comment: If you're not sure how to generate this sequence, then this isn't a programming question, it's a math question only.

Comment: for x in [1,3,7,15,31]:
    print(x)


It uses a loop. It prints those 5 numbers.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is much more of a math riddle than a programming question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The amount you add to the previous term is multiplied by two each time, so you can use another variable to store how much to add.

```
a = 1
add = 2
while a <= 31:
    print(a)
    a += add
    add *= 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = 2
while a <= 31:
  print(a - 1)
  a = a * 2
```

you can change the while loop to any number you wish and it will keep going

Answer (score 0):

If I got your sequence as you meant to, I think this is how it should reproduced:

```
last = 1
print(last)
for i in range(10):
    last =(last*2)+1 
    print(last)
```

output for 10 first elements:

```
1
3
7
15
31
63
127
255
511
1023
2047
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function is actually the 2 to the power of n minus 1.
You can easily define the function as :

```
def pow_func(n):
    return 2**n-1
```

Once you have that, you can easily incorporate it in your code (if you want to limit to 31):

```
for n in range(1, 6):
    print(pow_func(n))
```